# Поиск значений в словаре по элементам списка, которые соответствуют ключам словаря

Tags: python-3.x

имеется словарь:

```
dict = {'Оля': '1.8', 'Петя':'2.0', 'Саша':'3.8', 'Дима':'0.6', 'Катя':'2.1', 'Настя':'3.6', 'Аня':'0.2', 'Ира':'0.5', 'Марина':'3.2', 'Кристина':'0.2', 'Рома':'2.2'}
```

имеется список списков:

```
list = [['Оля', 'Дима', 'Аня'], ['Марина', 'Рома', 'Ира'], ['Саша', 'Настя', 'Петя']]
```

- пар ключ/значение в словаре больше, чем элементов в списке.
- элементы списка списков обязательно присутствуют в ключах словаря

Необходимо перемножить значения в словаре по отдельным спискам из списка и найти MAX, т.е.

['Оля', 'Дима', 'Аня'] = 1.8 * 0.6 * 0.2 = 0.216

['Марина', 'Рома', 'Ира'] = 3.2 * 2.2 * 0.5 = 3.52

['Саша', 'Настя', 'Петя'] = 3.8 * 3.6 * 2.0 = 27.36

вывод:

['Саша', 'Настя', 'Петя'] = 27.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не гнаться за однострочниками, то просто выполняем прямолинейную логику шаг за шагом

```
dic = {'Оля': '1.8', 'Петя':'2.0', 'Саша':'3.8', 'Дима':'0.6', 'Катя':'2.1', 'Настя':'3.6', 'Аня':'0.2', 'Ира':'0.5', 'Марина':'3.2', 'Кристина':'0.2', 'Рома':'2.2'}
lis = [['Оля', 'Дима', 'Аня'], ['Марина', 'Рома', 'Ира'], ['Саша', 'Настя', 'Петя']]

maxp = -1
for sub in lis:
    prod = 1
    for item in sub:
        prod *= float(dic[item])
    if prod > maxp:
        maxp = prod
        best = sub
print(best, maxp)

>>>   ['Саша', 'Настя', 'Петя'] 27.36
```

Comment: Благодарю - как раз то, что нужно!